# @font-face embeded fonts not working IE, but work from server IIS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iis, font-face

Currently, I am implementing roughly five different fonts using @font-face. The syntax for the declarations are correct. I am testing in Firefox, Chrome, and IE 8-10. I am not accessing the page using 'localhost' at any time.

1. Scenario: Accessing page using www.dev.site.com/page from server

   - Firefox: works
   - IE 8-10: works
   - Chrome: works
2. Scenario: Accessing page using www.dev.site.com/page from the outside server

   - Firefox: works
   - IE 8-10: does not work
   - Chrome: works

It is strange because I am not using localhost to access the site. I added Network Service to full control on the directory and that didn't seem to help.

What's happening, and how can I fix it?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sf_movie_posterregular';
    src: url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.svg#sf_movie_posterregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: So what's the actual difference between scenario 1 & 2?

Comment: ops, sorry mis typed. Scenario 2 is from outside the server. However in both instances they are sing the fully qualified domain name so I figured even from the server would require IIS and file permissions to be configured correctly.

Comment: Are there any errors (especially about CORS) listed in the F12 Developer Tools console?

Comment: Incidentally, "the syntax for this declarations correct" is a bad thing to say, since you're *assuming* it's correct, but clearly it's not working, so it's really too soon to rule that out.

Comment: Well it works when I am on the server so I assumed that is the case.
Was created with squirrel fonts or whatever that site is called. 

@font-face {
    font-family: 'sf_movie_posterregular';
    src: url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/customtitle-webfont.svg#sf_movie_posterregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

Comment: There are no entries being output to the console.